# First lettter of month in french should be capital using java

Tags: java

The issue is I write a code which contain a method that give us a date which is in "MMM-dd-YYYY" format in french language.
Code is bellow

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-YYYY", new Locale("FR"));
String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date());
```

But it shows some month contain 4 letter and all month have smallcaps like

```
févr-01-2016
```

How can I format it like this?

```
Fév-01-2016
```

Comment: Why do you want to? As far as I'm aware, French month names *don't* start with a capital letter - that's just the way it is.

Comment: basically in french february month is  denotes  février.that's why you are getting this output.if you use new Locale("FR") it display the output what you are getting now

Comment: see the french moth details in this link http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/calendar.htm

Comment: If you see the link http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-capitalization.htm french have standard not to capitalize the month,  so if you want to do that just convert the date and convert first letter in capital

Answer (score 3):

French month names are common names that aren't capitalized.

Dixit [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/majuscules-aux-noms-de-jours-et-de-mois):
Les noms des jours et des mois sont des noms communs qui forment une catégorie extrêmement limitée, et qui le serait encore quand bien même on y ajouterait les noms des jours et des mois révolutionnaires, comme quintidi ou décadi, germinal ou vendémiaire. **Comme ce sont des noms communs, ils ne doivent pas, sauf en début de phrase, être écrits avec une majuscule** et ils prennent, les uns et les autres, la marque du pluriel.

If the text is at the beginning of a sentence, then just use:

```
formattedDate = formattedDate.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + formattedDate.substring(1)
```

UPDATE: by the way, in French, the format "MMM-dd-YYYY" is **never** used. The order is always day, month then year.

Comment: Any another method to do it and I need to show always only 3 letters

Comment: @SaakshiAggarwal check my answer

Comment: @SaakshiAggarwal, about french month name abbreviations: the strings provided by SimpleDateFormat are OK.

Comment: @SaakshiAggarwal, about another method: no. With Java itself, you need to extract the first letter, capitalize it then re-merge it. For a shorter syntax, see any library such as Apache Commons or Google Guava.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils.capitalize(formattedDate)
```

[check doc -- WordUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow code for your need

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-YYYY", new Locale("FR"));

        String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date());
        String newWord = formattedDate.substring(0,3)+formattedDate.substring(3+1);

     String  formattedDate1= newWord.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+newWord.substring(1);

        System.out.println(formattedDate1);
```

Comment: I have different-different locale.so i need to write the code which doesn't effect the format given by another locale like new Locale("us") .This code is not be fit for us locale, And i need to use short syntax.

Comment: @SaakshiAggarwal did you check with new Local("us") using this code. nothing affected

Comment: out put is Feb01-2016  it have to be Feb-01-2016